# Flutter text in box decoration getting cut off

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am making a portfolio website as my first flutter project (It is really fun using flutter so far!), but my project card (I'm thinking box decoration) cuts the text off, here is my code:

```dart
margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(child:Image.network(
                    widget.image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
                Expanded( child:Container(
                    child: Text("ROK IMAGES", style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    )),
                )),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: _borderRadius,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                  spreadRadius: 5,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0, 2),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

If I posted the wrong amount of braces it's because of how i copy and pasted it.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Photo of my problem:

[image: Problem]

Comment: Can you show an image of the whole widget?

Comment: Sure! https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2RbR.png

Comment: use BoxFit.fill

Comment: On which widget? The text, the image, or the parent widget?

Comment: @RhinoCodes there could be lots of solutions to this problem. Decrease the size of the image container, avoid using an expanded widget for the text, increase the height of your card, etc. Try building in debug mode so that it displays the overflow error.

Comment: I am. I got rid of the overflow error with the expanded widget, without the expanded widget there is an overflow @PatrickMahomes

Comment: @p2kr didn't work

Comment: Wrap your column again in container and give it apropriate margin

Comment: or you could use FittedBox

Comment: I'll try that then

Comment: Column in container didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - Just had to make the image smaller than the container :D

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the text widget......If you are using vs code,just hover to text and click refactor....and click the option wrap with padding and give padding as required.

Comment: That didn't work - with EdgeInsets.all(15) it just moved down still getting cut off, https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZyIS.png

Comment: just add padding to the bottom with EdgeInsets.only(bottom: (value)) as required

Comment: When I do that it still overflows without Expanded, and does not with it

Answer (score 0):

Try to below **code** :

```
    Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    height: 200,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/insta.png',
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              "ROK IMAGES",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,
                // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Your output look like this [image]

Comment: I got it figured out by doing something similar before you commented (making container bigger than image)